# c++ How to convert DDS to png/jpg

Tags: visual-c++, windows-phone-8, png, jpeg, dds-format

I require a dds to png or jpg convertor in c++, has anyone accomplished just this task or come across a simple c++/c library for doing this.

I would rather not use Imagemagick-Magick++, as it is over kill for what I need.
Is there any alternatives?

The dds format is DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM I think, if this helps.

Comment: Have you considered [DirectXTex](http://directxtex.codeplex.com/) ?

Comment: Ah I should have mentioned I'm doing this on windows phone 8 so WIC is not available